# Oracle Stored Procedure to select from multiple procedures, Array as IN parameter and 1 dynamic condition based on the length of the array element

Tags: oracle, procedure

I have 3 procedures which will return different columns values to insert in same table.

All procedures take Array as parameter and values of array can be of two type. if type a then where name = "tin" and if type 2 then name  = "tan".

EX:

```
Array a = {a,b,b,a};
if(a){
name="tin"
}else{
name="tan"
}
```

how I will write a procedure to get all the values passing the array and 1 more condition based the length of array element.

Comment: In tags you mention Mysql and Oracle - for which one do you need?

Comment: That clearly isn't Oracle PL/SQL syntax.  So it's difficult to understand your scenario.  You need to provide more details.  As it stands, your question is not at all clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
   set serveroutput on
   CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE arrtype AS VARRAY(200) OF VARCHAR2(50);
   /

   created

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE arrtest (arr_in arrtype) IS
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1..arr_in.count LOOP
        if(arr_in(i)='a') then
        dbms_output.put_line('TIN');
    ELSIF(arr_in(i)='b') then
       dbms_output.put_line('TAN');
        else
    dbms_output.put_line('neither TIN nor TAN');
    end if;
      END LOOP;
    END;
    /

Procedure created

SQL>  DECLARE
  2     array1 arrtype;
  3   BEGIN
  4   array1 := arrtype();
  5   array1.EXTEND(3);
  6     array1(1) := 'a';
  7     array1(2) := 'b';
  8     array1(3) := 'c';
  9     arrtest(array1);
 10   END;
 11   /

TIN
TAN
neither TIN nor TAN
```